# R matrix/array sumproduct transformation

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, sumproduct

I'm trying to do a matrix sumproduct calculation with two matrixes. The sumproduct is with rows in one matrix with the column in another matrix.

```
set.seed(123)
y <- matrix(sample(1:6,6,FALSE), nrow=3, ncol=2) 
x <- matrix(sample(1:5,15,TRUE), nrow=5, ncol=3)

> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    4    3
[2,]    2    3    2
[3,]    2    3    3
[4,]    4    3    1
[5,]    3    5    5

> y
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    6    5
[3,]    2    1
```

Is would in the results wil have a cell value in [1,1] will be sumproduct of x[ 1 , ] and y[ , 1]. The cell value in [1,2] is sumproduct of x[ 1 , ] and y[ , 2]. The cell value in [2,1] is sumproduct of x[ 2 , ] and y[ , 1]. And so on. The end result should look like this

```
> result

         [,1] [,2] 
    [1,]   45   43 
    [2,]   28   25 
    [3,]   30   26 
    [4,]   32   32 
    [5,]   49   42
```

I can do this using a loop, but if there is a function that does this automatically it would be so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user20650 supplied the most appropriate answer.

It seems x %*% y, would have been sufficient

```
set.seed(123)
y <- matrix(sample(1:6,6,FALSE), nrow=3, ncol=2) 
x <- matrix(sample(1:5,15,TRUE), nrow=5, ncol=3)
x %*% y

> x %*% y
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   47   46
[2,]   32   32
[3,]   31   24
[4,]   18   16
[5,]   37   34
```

Thanks for all the responses. Your coding has taught me a lot about how R works and how to write script for certain functions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest next approach. There is a function called `crossprod()` but works for defined dimension of the matrices. You could check about it. Next code could be useful:

```
set.seed(123)
#Data
y <- matrix(sample(1:6,6,FALSE), nrow=3, ncol=2) 
x <- matrix(sample(1:5,15,TRUE), nrow=5, ncol=3)
```

The matrices:

```
x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    5    1
[2,]    4    3    1
[3,]    1    3    5
[4,]    2    1    3
[5,]    3    4    2

y
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    6    5
[3,]    2    1
```

The code:

```
#Code
z <-   t(sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i){
    x[i, ] %*% sapply(1:ncol(y), function(j) {y[,j]})}))
```

The output:

```
z
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   47   46
[2,]   32   32
[3,]   31   24
[4,]   18   16
[5,]   37   34
```

Comment: prob missing something but is this just `x %*% y`

Comment: @Duck, thanks this is great. I had no idea that you can do that with sapply. Thanks

Comment: @H.Cheung Nice! You know now how to do it! If you think this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it :) It is up to you!

Comment: @Duck, The other answer by Cole is just as great too though, so didn't know what to do. I'm fairly new here and don't know what the etiquette is here when two answers are equally as good? You are both winners in my view but i'll tick for you!  ICheers

Comment: @user20650 - OMG. You are right, that works! It was interesting going through all the suggested approaches. At least good for learning how R works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `outer` to operator on the indices of the matrices. The `Vectorize` allows us to combine the results within `outer`. If you need performance, I really think that using [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) would be relatively easy with a loop.

```r
set.seed(123)
y <- matrix(sample(1:6,6,FALSE), nrow=3, ncol=2) 
x <- matrix(sample(1:5,15,TRUE), nrow=5, ncol=3)

outer(seq_len(nrow(x)),
      seq_len(ncol(y)),
      FUN  = Vectorize(function(i, j) sum(x[i, ] * y[, j])))
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]   47   46
#> [2,]   32   32
#> [3,]   31   24
#> [4,]   18   16
#> [5,]   37   34
```

And out of curiosity, this took ~5 minutes to come up with a [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) solution:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix custom_crossprod(IntegerMatrix x, IntegerMatrix y) {
  int nrow = x.rows();
  int ncol = y.cols();
  IntegerMatrix ans(nrow, ncol);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
    IntegerVector x_tmp = x(i, _);
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
      ans(i, j) = sum(x_tmp * y(_, j));
    }
  }
  return(ans);
}
```

Bench Marks::

```r
bench::mark(
  use_outer = 
outer(seq_len(nrow(x)),
      seq_len(ncol(y)),
      FUN  = Vectorize(function(i, j) sum(x[i, ] * y[, j])))
, custom_crossprod(x, y)
)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
##  expression                 min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
##  <bch:expr>             <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
##1 use_outer              179.8us 191.2us     4394.   11.73KB     4.37
##2 custom_crossprod(x, y)   4.9us   6.6us   135309.    2.49KB     0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat solution, like a "for loop" but not. Thanks very much

Comment: Most of [tag:r] is like a "for loop" but not :). A lot of the loops are just hidden.

Comment: I didn't know that. I wrote something similar to the second code above. I felt that writing loops was inefficient, when there seems to be functions that do everything. Thanks